# In expo & react native typescript, VS code IntelliSense suggests 'react-native/types', not 'react-native'

Tags: typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code, expo, intellisense

My react native typescript IntelliSense is suggesting `react-native/types` instead of `react-native`. How can I solve it?

I installed my project with `npx create-expo-app MyApp --template Typescript`.

This is my `tsconfig.json`.

```
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

I have already installed `@types/react-native` as dev-dependency. This is my `package.json`.

```
"dependencies": {
    "expo": "~48.0.10",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/react": "~18.0.14",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.71.5",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  },
```

Comment: I am switching back to `Javascript`.

Comment: Oh God, it also happens with `Javascript` too. Let's uninstall and reinstall VS code.

Comment: Still happens. Should choose another IDE? SublimeText?

Comment: LOL. I created my own npm package which imports all of react native components and functions. And I install it in my project. Very bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

I use this config for all my projects. Try this once

```json
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "babel.config.js", "metro.config.js", "jest.config.js"],
  "jsx": "react-jsx",
  "baseUrl": "."
}
```

Comment: Not working. And I think you meant `
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,"jsx": "react-jsx",
  "baseUrl": "."
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "babel.config.js", "metro.config.js", "jest.config.js"],
}
Share
Edit
Follow
`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following line to your `tsconfig.json` file.
It worked for me. Worth a try.

```
"types": ["react", "react-native"]
```

Here is my `tsconfig.json` file

```
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "types": ["react", "react-native"]
  }
}
```

and here is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "expo": "~48.0.18",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.8",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/react": "~18.0.14",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.72.2",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  },
  "private": true
}
```